# fgets and sscanf to read file into an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a function that reads txt files that contain 2 double and int per line with a space as a delimiter, for example (data.txt):

3.1 2.5 1

3.4 4.5 2

.....

I implemented the function below, it takes as arguments the file name, pointers to 2 double and an int. Each pointer will be used to retrieve a column from the file. I used 
    fgets 
to get the line and then 
    sscanf 
to extract the three values from the line. The program crushes at run time (error: Windows has triggered a breakpont in program.exe )

... When I put a breaking point before returning from the main function the retrieved values are corrected but the program crushes when I hit continue.

To debug the function I added the following lines of code to the function ReadFile below:

```
if (buf[strlen(buf)-1] != '\0') 
{ 
    putchar(buf[strlen(buf)-1]); //surprisingly this line prints 1 instead of a space... 
    exit(1);
}
```

With this change the code exit without reaching the end of the function. I don't understand this because the buf variable is long enough to hold all the characters of one line from the sample file.

I would appreciate your comments to fix this problem.

Thank you.

```
bool ReadFile(const char* fileName, double* x, double* y, int* t, int size)
{
    FILE* fp;   
    char    buf[5000];
    fp = fopen( fileName, "r" );

    for( int i = 0; i < size && fgets(buf, 5000, fp) != NULL; i++)  
    {
        buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0'; 
        if (buf[strlen(buf)-2] != '\0') 
        {    
            putchar(buf[strlen(buf)-1]);//surprisingly this line prints 1 instead of a space...
            exit(1);       
        }

        sscanf(buf, "%lf %lf %d", &x[i], &y[i], &t[i]);


    }

    fclose(fp);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: C != C++, and you should generally tag only the one you are using/compiling. This looks like C.

Comment: This is a C function style used in a c++ file...

Comment: If this is C++, then tag as such. A C answer may not work with a C++ compiler, or be non-standard (such a VLA).

Comment: If it's C++ then why are you using all C functions?

Comment: `i < size` does nothing. You mean to use a `&&` instead of a comma operator.

Comment: There's probably nothing wrong with `buf`.  The problem is probably with the `x`, `y`, or `t` arrays you're passing in.  How are they allocated in the caller?

Comment: Your test isn't testing what you think. The previous line (setting the newline to a null char) CHANGES THE LENGTH OF THE STRING! So the test is testing the character before the null char.

Comment: Is it crashing on the first line?

Comment: yes x, y, and t are allocated in the main with double* x = new double[size], double* x = new double[size], and int* t = new int[size]

Comment: @ooga it craches at return true

Comment: @ooga I edited the code  i < size && fgets(buf, 5000, fp)... Same crash

Comment: I changed if (buf[strlen(buf)-1] != '\0') to if (buf[strlen(buf)-2] != '\0')  but still getting the same crash

Comment: That's idiotic. It should be (but would still be useless) `buf[strlen(buf)] != '\0'`. Just get rid of that junk. The code you've posted tells us nothing. Put together a complete program (as small as possible) that demonstrates the problem and post it.

Comment: Think and change the code again. Not from -1 to -2 but from -1 to...

Comment: Sorry guys... Problem solved....The problem was in the caller, the size was set to 1 (bug in another function)... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the caller, the size was set to 1 instead of the number of lines in the data file.